# Need some explanation on an example for Representation of General Linear Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am studying the following example on representation of general Linear groups. Before that I mention a brief description of representation of general linear groups in general framework.
Let consider the representation $(V, \rho)$ of $GL(C^{n})$ , the group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices, where $\rho : GL(C^{n}) \to GL(V)$ such that $\rho (A)=(\rho_{kl}(A))_{1 \leq k,l \leq N}$ and $N$ is the dimension of vector space $V$. The following representation sometimes is called $\textit{polynomial representation}$ as well. We say that $(V, \rho)$ is a polynomial representation of degee $d$ if the matrix entries $\rho_{kl} (A) = \rho_{kl} (a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots, a_{nn})$ are polynomial functions.

> **Example**. Let $V$ be the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $3$ in $x,y$, so 
>   $V=span \{ x^3,x^2y,xy^2, y^3 \} \cong C^4$ and $\rho$ be the group homomorphism,then we have
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{11}       & a_{12}  \\
>     a_{21}       & a_{22}  \\
>     %\hdotsfor{5} \\
>    % x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & 
> \end{bmatrix} $\to$  \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{11}^3 & a_{11}^2a_{12} & a_{11}a_{12}^2  & a_{12}^{3} \\
>     3a_{11}^2a_{21} & a_{11}^2a_{22}+2a_{11}a_{12}a_{21} & 2a_{11}a_{12}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}^2   & 3a_{12}^2a_{22} \\
>     3a_{11}a_{21}^2 & 2a_{11}a_{21}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}^2 & a_{11}a_{22}^2+2a_{12}a_{21}a_{22}   & 3a_{12}a_{22}^2  \\
>     a_{21}^3 & a_{21}^2a_{22} & a_{21}a_{22}^2 & a_{22}^3
> \end{bmatrix}
>   I need an explicit explanation on the entries of $4 \times 4$ matrix. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Well $x\mapsto a_{11}x+a_{21}y$ and $y\mapsto a_{12}x+a_{22}y$ so  $x^3\mapsto \dots$

Comment: This is all very confused. The example is of a specific representation of the group of $2\times 2$ matrices (not $n\times n$ in general). And it is given by having $x$ and $y$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and then extending the action of the group on that space to all polynomials by requiring the action to also respect the multiplication. This results in the given action on the degree $3$ homogeneous component as stated.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think it is clear where I say it is an example!! I did not say it is a general example.

Comment: I have no idea what your actual question is, but there is nothing "clear" here, and you don't say anywhere that this is an example for $n=2$. You are the one with the question, so you are the one that needs to make it clear if you want an answer.